# How to add scripts for udev to run

Tags: udev, nixos

I have several scripts i would like udev to run when a monitor is plugged/unplugged. I have added the extra udev rules, but i don't know how to add the scripts that i want udev to run.

I have tried pointing udev to the scripts outside of nix with:

```
RUN+="/home/myUser/scriptName.sh"
```

This failed on rebuild with the error:

```
/home/myUser/scriptName.sh is called in udev rules but not installed by udev
```

So how do i install scripts by udev?

Do i have to create nix expressions for the scripts and install them with everything else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**

This is an impure solution, and it means that `configuration.nix` alone won't get you quite there. I strongly discourage using this on servers.

On the other hand, I use this approach for my laptop, where I still have to fetch my dotfiles from somewhere else, pull work repositories, restore backups etc., so I have things which can't be described by nix expressions alone anyway.

**The answer**

This is the piece of my `configuration.nix` regarding `udev`, and it takes care of setting up an external monitor when the laptop is docked.

```
  services.udev = {
      extraRules = ''
        SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="add|remove", ENV{ID_VENDOR}=="Lenovo", ENV{ID_MODEL}=="Lenovo_ThinkPad_Dock", RUN+="${pkgs.bash}/bin/bash /home/hoodoo/.local/bin/dock_handler.sh"
      '';
  };
```

What cheats the nix interpreter here is the fact I call something properly installed and smuggle my script as an argument (and it's not going to have the capacity to figure out all possible options to all possible commands anytime soon).

In case anyone's curious, I've got the parts of the solution [here](https://ww.telent.net/2016/12/15/hotplug_scripts_in_nixos) and [here](https://gist.github.com/kyokley/169646c27ed2dcc470b6).